# Invalid credentials for repo.magento.com

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, composer, repository

I'm trying to install Magento 2.3 on a local Laragon install, but the composer install is failing because of this error:

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-invitation/magento-module-invitation-100.3.4.0.zip', aborting.
```

I've tried re-generating my marketplace access keys and tried using another account. Adobe is saying their servers are working fine from what I can tell. I've ensured that I'm putting the public key in the "username" prompt and the private key in the "password" prompt. I'm not saving my keys anywhere and am putting them in every time it asks.

~ Matt

Comment: Is this Magento Commerce or OpenSource what you're trying to install?

Comment: Please refer this link :- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html 2> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Invalid-credentials-for-https-repo-magento-com-packages-json/m-p/22526#M496

Comment: @PauGNU this is Magento Cloud, so I'm assuming Commerce.

Comment: @MohitPatel would this have to do with my MageID not being a Commerce related one? I've read somewhere that the package it's trying to download *isn't* a Commerce package...

Comment: HI @MattKrell, yes: your user doesn't have the permissions to download Magento Cloud. Unless you have purchased that Magento version subscription, you can't. If you're working for a client that has paid for it, he/she will have a magento account and they can grant access to your user.

Answer (score 2):

> At Magento root add **auth.json** and remove other **auth.json** or **auth.json.sample** file.

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "b2bf8b45105dce3bc6959628b2865433",
            "password": "23e0a6089d049486e96b637a8253d060"
        }
    }
}
```

> Here add your generated key

[Click Here to get your Key](https://marketplacesupport.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015773392-Access-Keys)

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your username and password (Public key and private key) in the auth.json file which is available in the Magento root directory.

If auth.json is not there then create it and then add these credentials into that file and then check it might resolve your issue.

Check this guide: https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/setup/first-time-setup-import-prepare.html#auth-json

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Magento 2.4.4 you can replace your generated key with
this key

```
./config/composer/auth.json
```

I hope it will be helpful to you